# XAML: Can you define application resources outside app.xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ui class collection that all have to share the same theme across all their instances. The values inside the theme are subject to dynamic change. Right now this is achieved by assigning a dynamic resource to the required properties and applying application level resources during runtime, for example:

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource sbL1}" \>
```

and in code i would call

```
Application.Current.Resources("sbL1") = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
```

This works fine during runtime but I get these annoying underlines in XAML designer mode. Obviously the answer would be to include sbL1 definition in app.xaml but i want this bunch of ui classes to be as PnP as possible, as in, add the folder to the project and done. So.. Can you define application resources outside app.xaml? Or some other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can define all your resources in a resource dictionary as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:options="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush"
                 Color="#FF171717"
                 options:Freeze="True"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush"
                 Color="#FFFFFFFF"
                 options:Freeze="True"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Add that resource dictionary into application level merged dictionaries as follows:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionartiesApplication.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add("<Path of Resource Dictionary>")
```

Then use these resources throughout your project as dynamic resource:

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" \>
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point, I can already use them, what i need is for XAML editor to stop complaining and programmatically adding a resourcedictionary doesn't change that.